# Sending and receive NSMutableArray as Bytes using GameKit

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, gamekit

I am trying to send an Array from one player to another.

I create a struct in the header

```
typedef struct {
    Message message;
    unsigned int numBytes;
    void * bytes;
} MessagePingBackToCaller;

typedef struct {
    MessageType messageType;
} Message;
```

And try to send with this:

```
-(void)sendOpponentRadar{

    MessagePingBackToCaller sendMessage;
    sendMessage.message.messageType = kMessageTypeRecievedRadarPing;
    NSData *pingData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[cover gatherAndReturnColumnNumbers]];

    sendMessage.bytes = pingData;

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&sendMessage length:sizeof(MessagePingBackToCaller)];    
    [self sendData:data];
}
```

And receive with this:

```
if (message->messageType == kMessageTypeRecievedRadarPing){

        MessagePingBackToCaller *messageSent = (MessagePingBackToCaller *)[data bytes];

        NSLog(@"Data : %@", messageSent->bytes);

        NSMutableArray *array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:messageSent->bytes];
        NSLog(@"Results : %@", array);
    }
```

However no luck, so I went looking around and found that @rwenderlich wrote a little helpful bit:

1. Convert NSArray to NSData
2. In struct, store an unsigned int numBytes, and a void * bytes
3. In numBytes, write the length of the NSData, and then write out the contents of the NSData
4. On the other side, read numBytes to see how many bytes to read next, then read in that amount of bytes and reverse the process (bytes->NSData->NSArray).

Im pretty good on 1 and 2... I believe, but i get lost on 3 and 4. Could someone please help me translate this into meaningful code?

Thanks!

Comment: i dont think this statement, NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&sendMessage length:sizeof(MessagePingBackToCaller)]; is returning what you expect, sizeof(MessagePinkBackToCaller) will not be the size of the actual sendMessage object, it will return the size of the MessagePinkBackToCaller class "space" which contains pointers and not actual objects, for one it will return void * as a pointer of 4 bytes, when in reality it can be of any size, something not reflected in sizeof( so in this case you cannot use sizeof..

Comment: some of that might have gone over my head, but what might you suggest?

Comment: Is there a reason ur send message is a c struct?

Comment: Well I just don't know any other way :/

Comment: just posted an answer, check i tou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use NSKeyedArchiver to do the trick, dont use the c struct, make it an objective-c class, get data from the thing using NSKeyedArchiver and send that, then just unarchive in the other side, heres an example for an arbitrary class

interface

```
@interface GameState : NSObject
{
   //enum for session state
    SessionState _currentState;
    NSData *_data;
    NSString *_message;

    NSDate *_timestamp;

}

@property(nonatomic,retain) NSDate *timestamp;

@property(assign) SessionState currentState;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSData *data;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *message;
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder;
```

implementation

```
@implementation GameState
@synthesize message=_message ,  currentState= _currentState, data=_data;
@synthesize  timestamp=_timestamp;
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
        _killPlayback=FALSE;
        _lastPacket=FALSE;
        _number=0.0;
        _pass=FALSE;
        _timestamp=NULL;

    }

    return self;
}
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    [coder encodeObject:_timestamp forKey:@"Timestamp"];

    [coder encodeObject:_message forKey:@"Message"];
    [coder encodeObject:_data forKey:@"Data"];
    [coder encodeInt:_currentState forKey:@"State"];



}
// Decode an object from an archive
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super init];
    _message  = [[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"Message"] retain];
    _data  = [[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"Data"] retain];
    _currentState=(SessionState)[coder decodeIntForKey:@"State"];
    _timestamp=[[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"Timestamp"] retain];
    return self;
}
@end
```

now you can get data from the object like

```
-(NSData*)dataFromObject:(id)obj
{
    return [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:obj];
}
```

and an object from the data

```
-(id)objectFromData:(NSData*)data
{
    return [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
}
```

and your workflow becomes
on the sender side

```
GameState *state=..;
NSData* data=[self dataFromObject:state];
//send the data
```

and on the receiving side

```
GameState *state=[self objectFromData:data];
```

hope it helps

Comment: Ok so just trying to clear this all up in my head. So I store all the data that I want into GameState, i.e. NSStrings and Arrays and such as both _message and _data? Once that is done I then compact it all as NSData using dataFromObject: and then use my sending method to send the data over the wire and unpack on the other end?

Comment: Also could you please write me a quick example of how to use the initWithCoder: (how to pass in the _message and _data?)

Comment: AHHH!!! Never mind I got it working! However I need to take a longer look at NSCoder, because I think I butchered your code. But thank you so much for your explanation.

Comment: Note for other people this will only work if your class has the NSCoder protocol ie so NSManagedObject won't work because it doesn't implement that protocol

Answer (score 0):

You might also try the following to get compressed data (about 1/5 the size of the original):

```
-(NSData*)compressedMatchDataFromMatchState:(NSMutableDictionary*)matchState
{
    NSError* error = nil;
    NSData* compressedMatchData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:matchState format:NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0 options:0 error:&error]; 
   return compressedMatchData;
 }

-(NSMutableDictionary*)matchStateFromCompressedMatchData:(NSData*)compressedMatchData
{
    NSError* error = nil;
    NSPropertyListFormat plf = NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves;
    NSMutableDictionary* matchState = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:compressedMatchData options:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves format:&plf error:&error];
    return matchState;
 }
```