# Sending Data via Message Object Using NSKeyedArchiver

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm implementing a multiplayer game where I have to send data between players using:

```
 [self sendData:data mode:GKMatchSendDataReliable];
```

Instead of using multiple c-structs like in this tutorial (http://www.raywenderlich.com/3325/how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-game-center-tutorial-part-22), I created a Message object and a subclass of Message called Submessage. The subclasses are created so I avoid sending unnecessary variables in each message, to minimize the size of each packet sent. I then used NSCoding to encode and decode the messages.

The classes look something like the following:

**Message.h**

```
 @interface Message : NSObject <NSCoding>

 @property int messageType;

 - (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder;

 - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder;
```

**Message Coder Methods**

```
-(void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder{
     [coder encodeInt:messageType forKey:@"messageType"];
}
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super init];
    messageType = [coder decodeIntForKey:@"messageType"];
    return self;
}
```

**Submessage.h**

```
 @interface Submessage : Message <NSCoding>

 @property float additionalParameter1;

 - (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder;

 - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder;
```

**Submessage Coder Methods**

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder{
    [super encodeWithCoder:coder];
    [coder encodeFloat:additionalParameter1 forKey:@"float"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super init];
    [self initWithCoder:coder];
    floatParameter1 = [coder decodeFloatForKey:@"floatParameter1"];
    return self;
}
```

After I receive the data, I use the following method to unarchive it:

```
 Message *thisMessage = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

However, this doesn't work when I'm sending Submessage. How can I determine whether data is of type Message or Submessage? How should I implement this so that it would work like in the c-struct case?

Comment: By _doesn't work_, do you mean to say that `[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:submessage]]` returns an instance of `Message` instead of `Submessage` ?

Comment: Also you may want to show how you implemented your `initWithCoder` methods.

Comment: You are concerned about the size of the packet, yet you are sending archived data. Have you checked how huge keyed archives get due to the overhead? Instead of 8 bytes for a point you may be sending over 200 bytes.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D yea...ideally I'd like to implement a c-struct, but I have some messages where I need to send NSArray of NSNumbers. I couldn't convert these to int[] / c-struct format. I read this thread that said to use an object: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071435/sending-and-receive-nsmutablearray-as-bytes-using-gamekit

Comment: @Taum I've included my Coder methods. I think there's something wrong with them. When I code my Submessage, how do I ensure that MessageType in Message is coded and decoded as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You subclass initWithCoder doesn't seem correct. According to the docs:

> If the superclass adopts the NSCoding protocol, you start by assigning
>   of the return value of initWithCoder: to self:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        // Implementation continues.
    }
    return self;
}
```

But since you're saying message length should be minimized, I'd suggest using MessagePack (http://msgpack.org/) for converting to a compact binary representation. You'll have to handle a bit more yourself but it should be much more efficient :)

Comment: Also, use your debugger to check if the Submessage's initWithCoder: is indeed being called!

Comment: Thanks, and also for the suggestion to use MessagePack!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to determine at runtime what kind of object gets unarchived. You can test its class just like you can with any object and then use it appropriately. Like so:

```
id obj = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
if ([obj isKindOfClass:[Submessage class]]) {
    Submessage * submessage = (Submessage *)obj;
    // do something with submessage
} else if ([obj isKindOfClass:[Message class]]) {
    Message * message = (Message *)obj;
    // do something with message
}
```

(`-isKindOfClass:` will detect subclasses, which is why the first conditional needs to be the check for the subclass here.)